# Use XSLT to process WSDL and generate SOAP requests

Tags: web-services, xslt, soap, wsdl, soapui

Can I read WSDL and generate soapUI-like requests using XSLT?
Could you provide a template?

Comment: Yes , you can process with XSLT any XML document. As for your request "Could you provide a template?" -- this isn't a question at all. The asker is the one who must define the question in detail -- provide a source XML document, provide the wanted output of the transformation of this XML document, describe any requirements that the XSLT transformation must implement. Not having provided these means that most probably you don't have a question at all.

Comment: I mean whether anybody has ever transformed WSDL into SOAP envelopes.

Comment: Most probably yes -- provide a source XML document (WSDL) and the exact wanted result (SOAP) and explain the rules for the transformation -- like which how to calculate the contents of every node in the result from the nodes in the source. Then many people here would be able to give you the transformation that produces this result.

Comment: If I provide a source and result then people will be leaning to produce a solution for that special case. I would like to be able to create request samples for any WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not find an answer anywhere I decided to contruct the [Soap Envelope Generator](http://blog.eduardocastro.info/2012/04/transform-wsdl-into-soap-envelopes.html) by myself. The full XSLT file is on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/soap-envelope-generator/).